# Is there a more efficient way to replace NULL with NA in a list?

Tags: r, performance, list, null

I quite often come across data that is structured something like this:

```
employees <- list(
    list(id = 1,
             dept = "IT",
             age = 29,
             sportsteam = "softball"),
    list(id = 2,
             dept = "IT",
             age = 30,
             sportsteam = NULL),
    list(id = 3,
             dept = "IT",
             age = 29,
             sportsteam = "hockey"),
    list(id = 4,
             dept = NULL,
             age = 29,
             sportsteam = "softball"))
```

In many cases such lists could be tens of millions of items long, so memory concerns and efficiency are always a concern.

I would like to turn the list into a dataframe but if I run:

```
library(data.table)
employee.df <- rbindlist(employees)
```

I get errors because of the NULL values. My normal strategy is to use a function like:

```
nullToNA <- function(x) {
    x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
    return(x)
}
```

and then:

```
employees <- lapply(employees, nullToNA)
employee.df <- rbindlist(employees)
```

which returns

```
   id dept age sportsteam
1:  1   IT  29   softball
2:  2   IT  30         NA
3:  3   IT  29     hockey
4:  4   NA  29   softball
```

However, the nullToNA function is very slow when applied to 10 million cases so it'd be good if there was a more efficient approach.

One point that seems to slow the process down it the is.null function can only be applied to one item at a time (unlike is.na which can scan a full list in one go).

Any advice on how to do this operation efficiently on a large dataset?

Comment: have you tried do.call with rbind? like so `employee.df<-do.call("rbind",employees)`

Comment: Does the original data actually say "NULL" if null, or is it just empty there?

Comment: The original data has NULL values. It was generated by scraping JSON files and converting them through rjson.

Comment: In a general case, if the original (scraped) dataset is already a data.frame (e.g., from `XML::readHTMLTable()`), and the NULL cells are simply 0-length character strings, use the following: `df <- data.frame(apply(df, c(1,2), FUN=function(x) ifelse(x=="",NA,x)))`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Many efficiency problems in R are solved by first changing the original data into a form that makes the processes that follow as fast and easy as possible. Usually, this is matrix form.

If you bring all the data together with `rbind`, your `nullToNA` function no longer has to search though nested lists, and therefore `sapply` serves its purpose (looking though a matrix) more efficiently. In theory, this should make the process faster.

Good question, by the way.

```
> dat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(employees, rbind))
> dat
     id dept age sportsteam
[1,] 1  "IT" 29  "softball"
[2,] 2  "IT" 30  NULL      
[3,] 3  "IT" 29  "hockey"  
[4,] 4  NULL 29  "softball"

> nullToNA(dat)
     id dept age sportsteam
[1,] 1  "IT" 29  "softball"
[2,] 2  "IT" 30  NA        
[3,] 3  "IT" 29  "hockey"  
[4,] 4  NA   29  "softball"
```

Comment: This is certainly faster than my current approach. It's a shame to lose the speed of rbindlist for the concatenation though, as that is a lot faster than do.call(rbind, employees). That might just be the tradeoff here though.

Comment: In that case why don't you do this `lapply(employees, function(x) ifelse(x == "NULL", NA, x))` and then use `rbindlist`

Comment: This would be very neat, but the resulting columns (after conversion to data.frame) are lists, which creates problems.  See `dat = data.frame(dat); dat[,1]`..

Comment: Everyone, this is a really bad answer.  Please don't use it.  @JonM - if you could, please remove the checkmark so I can delete it.

Answer (score 7):

A tidyverse solution that I find easier to read is to write a function that works on a single element and map it over all of your NULLs.

I'll use @rich-scriven's rbind and lapply approach to create a matrix, and then turn that into a dataframe.

```
library(magrittr)

dat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(employees, rbind)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

dat
#>   id dept age sportsteam
#> 1  1   IT  29   softball
#> 2  2   IT  30       NULL
#> 3  3   IT  29     hockey
#> 4  4 NULL  29   softball
```

Then we can use `purrr::modify_depth()` at a depth of 2 to apply `replace_x()`

```
replace_x <- function(x, replacement = NA_character_) {
  if (length(x) == 0 || length(x[[1]]) == 0) {
    replacement
  } else {
    x
  }
}

out <- dat %>% 
  purrr::modify_depth(2, replace_x)

out
#>   id dept age sportsteam
#> 1  1   IT  29   softball
#> 2  2   IT  30         NA
#> 3  3   IT  29     hockey
#> 4  4   NA  29   softball
```

Answer (score 5):

A two step approach creates a dataframe after combing it with `rbind`:

```
employee.df<-data.frame(do.call("rbind",employees))
```

Now replace the NULL's, I am using "NULL" as R doesn't put NULL when you load the data and is reading it as character when you load it.

```
employee.df.withNA <- sapply(employee.df, function(x) ifelse(x == "NULL", NA, x))
```

Answer (score 2):

I often find `do.call()` functions hard to read. A solution I use daily (with a MySQL output containing `"NULL"` character values):

```
NULL2NA <- function(df) {
  df[, 1:length(df)][df[, 1:length(df)] == 'NULL'] <- NA
  return(df)
}
```

But for all solutions: please remember that `NA` cannot be used for calculation without `na.rm = TRUE`, but with `NULL` you can. `NaN` gives the same problem.
For example:

```
> mean(c(1, 2, 3))
2

> mean(c(1, 2, NA, 3))
NA

> mean(c(1, 2, NULL, 3))
2

> mean(c(1, 2, NaN, 3))
NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

All of these solutions (I think) are hiding the fact that the data table is still a lost of lists and not a list of vectors (I did not notice in my application either until it started throwing unexpected errors during `:=`).
Try this:

`data.table(t(sapply(employees, function(x) unlist(lapply(x, function(x) ifelse(is.null(x),NA,x))))))`

I believe it works fine, but I am not sure if it will suffer from slowness and can be optimized further.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to simply `map_dfr` over the list, which immediately yields the correct result:

```
> map_dfr(employees, ~ .x)
# A tibble: 4 × 4
     id dept    age sportsteam
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>     
1     1 IT       29 softball  
2     2 IT       30 NA        
3     3 IT       29 hockey    
4     4 NA       29 softball
```

However, if a column has no non-NULL values, it will be omitted from the output:

```
> list(list(a = 1, b = NULL, c = 3), list(a = 4, b = NULL, c = 6)) |> 
+   map_dfr(~ .x)
# A tibble: 2 × 2
      a     c
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3
2     4     6
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sapply(x, is.null)` `match(list(NULL), x)` could be used to speed up the conversion from `NULL` to `NA` in a list.

```r
lapply(employees, \(x) `[<-`(x, match(list(NULL), x), NA))
```

Benchmark

```r
bench::mark(
sapply = lapply(employees, \(x) `[<-`(x, sapply(x, is.null), NA)),
match = lapply(employees, \(x) `[<-`(x, match(list(NULL), x), NA)) )
#  expression      min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 sapply       82.6µs 88.8µs    11142.    4.13KB    47.1   4971    21      446ms
#2 match        50.7µs   57µs    17272.    4.13KB     6.47  8006     3      464ms
```