# r - data frame of lists into a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

**Background**

I'm querying a mongodb database to find a document:

```
library(rmongodb)
...
res <- mongo.find.one(m, n, q, f)  # <~~ returns BSON 
res <- mongo.bson.to.list(res)     # <~~ converts BSON to list
```

I'm then using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5533643/4002530) to try and convert it to a data frame

```
df <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(res[[1]], '[', seq(max(sapply(res[[1]],length))))))
```

However, this gives me a data frame of lists (subsetted here for convenience):

**data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(horse_id = list(17643L, 4997L, 20047L, 9914L, 
17086L, 12462L, 18490L, 17642L, 26545L, 27603L, 14635L, 13811L, 
27719L, 31585L, 9644L), start_1400m = list(14.76, 14.3, 14.48, 
15.11, 14.65, 14.63, 14.85, 14.54, 14.93, 14.5, 14.78, NULL, 
NULL, NULL, NULL), `1400m_1200m` = list(12.96, 12.47, 12.47, 
13.02, 12.65, 12.92, 13.11, 12.37, 13, 12.84, 12.79, NULL, 
NULL, NULL, NULL)), .Names = c("horse_id", "start_1400m", 
"1400m_1200m"), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")

> head(df)
    horse_id start_1400m 1400m_1200m
1    17643       14.76       12.96
2     4997        14.3       12.47
3    20047       14.48       12.47
4     9914       15.11       13.02
5    17086       14.65       12.65
6    12462       14.63       12.92
```

**Issue**

I would like to `library(reshape2); melt` and then plot this data using `ggplot2`, but as expected I `can't melt data.frames with non-atomic columns`.

```
> melt(df, id.vars=c("horse_id"))
Error: Can't melt data.frames with non-atomic 'measure' columns
```

How can I convert this data to a 'standard' data frame (i.e. not a data frame of lists?), or `melt` it as is?

**Update**

I hadn't properly considered the `NULL`s in the data. Using a combination of [a comment in this question - replacing NULL with NA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22870198/4002530) and [this answer - Convert List to DF with NULLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15798116/4002530) I came up with

```
d <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", df))

library(plyr)
d <- rbind.fill(lapply(d, function(f) {
  data.frame(Filter(Negate(is.null), f))
}))

names(d) <- sub("X","",names(d))      #<~~ clean the names
d <- melt(d, id.vars=c("horse_id"))   #<~~ melt for use in ggplot2
```

This replaces the `NULL`s with `NA`s and allows me to `melt` the data. However, I'm still not fully *au fait* with what each step is doing yet, or whether this is the right approach.

Comment: What is the desired output? What about `melt(lapply(df, unlist))`?

Comment: Definitely do not use sapply since that tries to convert its output to a list.  According to comment in your reference, it would be best to use vapply but I would settle for apply and wrap it with unlist to make sure the output is not a list.  I may be necessary to move unlist a level deeper if you still get an X of lists.

Comment: @AnandaMahto - thanks for the suggestion, but that method loses the relationship between the `horse_id` and the `start_1400m`, `1400m_1200m` values (even though some are `NULL`), does it not?

Answer (score -1):

It is normal for data.frames created from vectors or lists to have those objects represented as lists in dput() output and that is not usually a problem because it still works as a data.frame.

For example:

```
> a = list(1, 2, 3)
> b = list(4, 5, 6)
> df = data.frame(a)
> df = rbind(b, df)
> df
   X1 X2 X3
1   4  5  6
2   1  2  3
> s = sum(df[,2])
> s
[1] 7
> str(df)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ X1: num  4 1
 $ X2: num  5 2
 $ X3: num  6 3
> dput(df)
structure(list(X1 = c(4, 1), X2 = c(5, 2), X3 = c(6, 3)), .Names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
>
```

Comment: Did you actually try `str(df)` on the data provided by the OP. It is completely different from yours.

Comment: The OP - I guess you mean tospig - did not provide data to test. However, tospig showed 'mongo.bson.to.list(res)' that indicates capability to convert whatever it is into a list. Provided that is done there is no reason it should not work as I demonstrated.  However, if not then it would need to be converted into the right kind of list and that should be a simple matter of splitting it correctly,

Comment: The OP *did* provide the data set. Try reading the question. @Anandas solution will solve this issue taking the data *as is*.