# R: Easier way to change 0s in list of matrices into NAs?

Tags: r, list, na

I want to convert all 0s in the matrices of a list into NAs. I figured out a way how to achieve this task. However, it is too complex and I think there should be an easy way how to do it. Here some example data:

```
ABlue <- list("111.2012"=matrix(c(1, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0),
                            nrow = 1, byrow = T),
          "112.2012"=matrix(c(6, 2, 2, 0, 3, 1),
                            nrow = 1, byrow = T),
          "111.2011"=matrix(c(3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 9),
                            nrow = 1, byrow = T),
          "112.2011"=matrix(c(1, 2, 0, 0, 7, 0),
                            nrow = 1, byrow = T))
CNTRYs <- c("USA", "GER", "UK", "IT", "CND", "FRA")
ABlue <- lapply(ABlue  , "colnames<-",  CNTRYs ) # gets names from Country list
```

Important is that the original matrices already have Country names as colnames, so it would be nice to match with this list (ABlue).

Here the way I use until now:

```
ABlue.df<-data.frame(do.call("rbind",ABlue)) # two step approach to replace 0 with NA according to: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870198/is-there-a-more-efficient-way-to-replace-null-with-na-in-a-list"
ABlue.df.withNA <- sapply(ABlue.df, function(x) ifelse(x == 0, NA, x))
ABlueNA <- split(ABlue.df.withNA, 1:NROW(ABlue.df.withNA)) # is again a list (of vectors)  
names(ABlueNA) <- names(ABlue) # list with old names
ABlueNAdf <- lapply(ABlueNA, function(x) as.data.frame(x)) # turned into list of dfs of one column
ABlueNAdfT <- lapply(ABlueNAdf, function(x) t(x)) # transponed to list of dfs of one row and 206 cols
ABlueNAdfTnam <- lapply(ABlueNAdfT  , "colnames<-",  CNTRYs ) # gets names from Country list
ABlueNAdfTnam <- lapply(ABlueNAdfTnam  , "rownames<-",  1:NROW(ABlueNAdfTnam[1]) )
ABlue2 <- ABlueNAdfTnam
```

Ideas how to reduce lines and complexity? Thanks

**Edit:** I want to have the same structure as in the original data!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `replace`, like this:

```
lapply(ABlue, function(x) replace(x, x == 0, NA))
# $`111.2012`
#      USA GER UK IT CND FRA
# [1,]   1  NA  6 NA   1  NA
# 
# $`112.2012`
#      USA GER UK IT CND FRA
# [1,]   6   2  2 NA   3   1
#
# $`111.2011`
#      USA GER UK IT CND FRA
# [1,]   3   2 NA NA   1   9
#
# $`112.2011`
#      USA GER UK IT CND FRA
# [1,]   1   2 NA NA   7  NA
```

Or, as @roland suggested:

```
lapply(ABlue, function(x) {x[x == 0] <- NA; x})
```

Or, if you have a pipe addiction:

```
library(purrr)
ABlue %>% map(~ replace(.x, .x == 0, NA))
```

Comment: which basically is `lapply(ABlue, function(x) {x[x == 0] <- NA; x})`.

Comment: @N.Varela, no problem. Thanks for posting a reproducible example as well as showing the attempts you've already made.

Comment: Alternative approach: `ABlue %>% unlist() %>% replace(.==0,NA) %>% relist(d)` (uses `dplyr` for piping)

Comment: @MaratTalipov, "purrr" would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `for`.

```
for (i in 1:length(ABlue)) {
  ABlue[[i]][ABlue[[i]]==0] <- NA
}

ABlue
# $`111.2012`
#      USA GER UK IT CND FRA
# [1,]   1  NA  6 NA   1  NA
# 
# $`112.2012`
#      USA GER UK IT CND FRA
# [1,]   6   2  2 NA   3   1
#
# $`111.2011`
#      USA GER UK IT CND FRA
# [1,]   3   2 NA NA   1   9
#
# $`112.2011`
#      USA GER UK IT CND FRA
# [1,]   1   2 NA NA   7  NA
```

I'm wondering do we have any other functions to iterate over a list except `lapply` and `for`.