# Change NULL to NA in list without transformation

Tags: r, null, purrr

I have a list which I am turning into a dataframe. The list comes back from an API, and it contains some `NULL` values. There are questions on SO on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379021/function-to-change-null-to-na) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870198/is-there-a-more-efficient-way-to-replace-null-with-na-in-a-list), but they either deal with dataframes, or in the case of the second link, the OP was encouraged to transform to a dataframe first. I want to keep the list structure.

I'm parsing it in the following fashion, here is some example data:

```
example <- list(
  list(
    ID = "1",
    Name = "Joe",
    Middle_name = "Alan",
    Surname = "Smith"
  ),
  list(
    ID = "2",
    Name = "Sarah",
    Middle_name = NULL,
    Surname = "Jones"
  ),
  list(
    ID = "3",
    Name = "Robert",
    Middle_name = "Myles",
    Surname = "McDonnell"
  )
)

N <- NA_character_

df <- tibble::tibble(
  id = purrr::map_chr(example, .null = N, "ID"),
  name = purrr::map_chr(example, .null = N, "Name"),
  middle = purrr::map_chr(example, .null = N, "Middle_name"),
  surname = purrr::map_chr(example, .null = N, "Surname")
)


> df
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     id   name middle   surname
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>     <chr>
1     1    Joe   <NA>     Smith
2     2  Sarah   <NA>     Jones
3     3 Robert   <NA> McDonnell
```

It appears this issue has some history in the purrr [repo](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/231), but when I use purrr functions like `is_empty()` or `compact()`, I either get an error or it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how I could achieve this, preferably by keeping to the `tibble` & `map_chr` method I'm using above?

Comment: Why do you say "I want to keep the list structure" when you really want to turn it into a data frame. You do want to turn it into a data frame yes?

Comment: Eventually, but I'd like to do it by using purrr on the list in the manner above.

Comment: What about `map_df(transpose(example), ~map_chr(.,~ifelse(is.null(.),NA,.)))`?

Comment: That definitely keeps it within the purrr framework, and works nicely (thanks!), but transposes it first, so I wouldn't be able to to use the tibble approach above. Best answer yet, though.

Comment: I just updated to the development version of *purrr* and your example works just fine as is except for a small typo.  In `example` you use "Middle_name" but in `map_chr` you refer to "Middle_Name".

Comment: @aosmith Well, whaddya know!! I knew there was a purrr solution. Not quite the answer I was expecting, but if you write it up as answer, I'll happily accept it. Thanks, it works great, I just checked it.

Comment: Doing it with N `map_chr` functions is iterating over the whole list N times. Doing it an element at a time, like with lapply and `rbind` iterates over the list once. A quick benchmark test shows me the `map_chr` approach is ten times slower. That's the price you pay for being "tidy".

Comment: @Spacedman thanks :-)

Comment: @Spacedman Using `map_chr()` N times is equivalent to using `vapply()` N times. There's nothing tidyverse specific about it. Just benchmarked with `bind_rows()` and `flatten_chr()`, the "tidy" version is actually faster than the proposed base version. More to the point, we've been thinking about taking a column-spec approach for that kind of problems. It would bring the `readr` API to the task of creating data frames from lists and might be handy for heterogeneous lists of lists.

Comment: @lionel, thanks for the info. I find this approach really useful for dealing with messy internet data, badly-written APIs etc. Often I need to work with the list for a while before I turn everything into a dataframe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're example does work with the development version of *purrr*.

The `NULL` rows is causing problems for approaches, such as using `dplyr::bind_rows`, that would otherwise work to collapse a list of lists into a tibble.  A work-around to remove the `NULL` row is to loop through and `flatten` each list.  Looping via `map_df` binds the rows and gives your desired result.

```
map_df(example, flatten)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
     ID   Name Middle_name   Surname
  <chr>  <chr>       <chr>     <chr>
1     1    Joe        Alan     Smith
2     2  Sarah        <NA>     Jones
3     3 Robert       Myles McDonnell
```